# How to break multiple divs in next line if can't fit

Tags: css

I want to put multiple divs in same row and if they cant fit to break to next line.I want this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/218JB.png) instead of this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJFbz.png)

```css
.cardContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  min-width: 185.17px;
  height: 88px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div className="cardContainer">
  <div className="card">A</div>
  <div className="card">A</div>
  <div className="card">A</div>
  <div className="card">A</div>
  <div className="card">A</div>
  <div className="card">A</div>
  <div className="card">A</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: `display: flex` in parent element will suffice (and children as `display: block` and make sure they have a width somehow)

Answer (score 0):

CSS Flexbox would be your friend:

```css
.cardContainer {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.card {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width:20%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardContainer">
  <div class="card">A</div>
  <div class="card">A</div>
  <div class="card">A</div>
  <div class="card">A</div>
  <div class="card">A</div>
  <div class="card">A</div>
  <div class="card">A</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  gap: 10px 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <div class='item'></div>
 <div class='item'></div>
 <div class='item'></div>
 <div class='item'></div>
 <div class='item'></div>
 <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not really the right answer. @Xaos You ask for wrapping the divs (https://i.stack.imgur.com/218JB.png) . this solution nowrap.